# Configure gitg to use UTF8

Tags: linux, git, utf-8, git-gui

gitg doesn't display correctly git diff of UTF8 files, even while

- git does it correctly (as seen on the console)
- gitg correctly displays UTF8 files (not diff)

Is it possible to configure it to correctly display diff of UTF8 encoded files ? If so how ?

**EDIT :**

barti_ddu helped me realize that what seems to happen, in fact, is that gitg guess the encoding from the received diff file.

I have this problem when I replace badly encoded chars by well encoded ones : the first one in the diff is the bad one, which probably leads to a bad guess (and gives the impression I'm replacing well encoded chars by bad ones) :

[image]

So the (less important) goal would be to force gitg decode diff as UTF8 instead of guessing.

Comment: can't reproduce it (even if locale is forced to non-unicode one), what version of `gitg` are you using?

Comment: @barti_ddu I edited : I have this problem for diffs. The version is 0.2.4.

Comment: you mean changes diff (http://postimage.org/image/hthjg7smb/)?

Comment: @barti_ddu I updated my question. In fact I have no problem if there is no badly encoded chars in the diff.

Comment: it _may_ be possible to hack this by creating alias to 'diff' command which would force encoding; however this will probably require digging gitg sources to learn how does it produce diffs and may be not possible at all without patching them.